# +CMS ERROR 41 on Telit Modem

Tags: sms, modem, at-command

I am a developer, working on "Telit" GE865-Quad using AT commands.

I am planning an application, witch sends SMS when certain condition occurs. When the application does not send SMS the modem is shut-down (Therefore every time I want to send SMS I have to turn on the modem). This application sends 3 SMS to different numbers one after the other.

The application is working just fine. The problem apear after a while (after sending certain amount of SMS), when I give the command to send SMS I get **"+CMS ERROR 41"** ("Temporary failure"). Once this message appear, every time I try to send SMS I get the same ERROR - It is like the SIM card is stuck. The only way I have found to get rid of this error is to enter the SIM card to my privet phone and send SMS.

I have spoken to "Telit" representative and he could not give a satisfying answer other then adding more delay between messages.

This is some of the relevant code :

(Turning on sequence)  // From "Telit" GE865-Quad DataSheet

> **#QSS: 3**    //Before I start working with the modem i wait for this response with means the SIM is ready to use and the registration is to cellular network is complete*/

**AT+CMGF=1**    // Text Mode

> OK

**AT+CMGS=+xxxxxxxxxxxx**    // My number.

> "This is the message i want to send"    //Preparing the desired message require some coding But I think this is irrelevant to the subject.

//Delay for 3 secs//

And again : **AT+CMGS=+xxxxxxxxxxxx**    // My number.

> "This is the message I want to send"

//Delay for 3 secs//

(The same thing one more time)

The questions are:

1. Why does it happen, what am I doing wrong??
2. How can I unblock the SIM? What does the phone do so I can keep sending SMS?
   The purpose is the keep sending SMS automatically.

This is the first time I publish a message in this website so if something is unclear please let me know. :)

Thanks for all the helpers.
Itay.

Comment: Is the SIM still blocked after you have powered the modem down and switched it on again?  Is there a "reset" AT command that you could send to the modem that would reset it without powering down and up? (this would probably be manufacturer specific).

Comment: Hi, yes. Even after I reset the modem or turning it off and on the SIM stays blocked.

Comment: **UPDATE** - The "Telit" modem had firmware version 10.00.003. I updated to firmware version 10.00.008 (Which is the latest, at this moment) and the problem is gone (or at least it had not happened so far...). So if someone encounter this problem I would suggest to start with firmware update.

Comment: @user3239557 have you found a solution to this yet? I am having this problem intermittently, get and error one minute, send a SMS successfully the next. Not sure if it is a Telit issue, network issue, or SIM issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I did a firmware update to my modem and it works fine now. On the other hand I am not sure what the problem was, so I can not be sure it resolved. Did you check the necessary timeouts for the actions you like to preform?

Answer (score 0):

today i encountered this +CMS ERROR: 41 error, many times.
There was about 40 unread messages in the receiving modem.
After i deleted all received messages error disappeared.
I think may be operator is protecting customers from spam.
Dmitri

Answer (score 0):

It is due Either SMS service on your SIM is not available or your SMS subscription is expired.